# elif python3.5.3 error don't know why

Tags: python-3.x

what I am  trying to do is  just  simple + - * /.There is To reasons I am writing this I am rusty and to well cuz I love programming. Beacuse I am rusty I'm going over  loops and case statements then going to program a text game then will a programming challenge for fun.here is the link if you want it [programming challenge](http://bowtiebeej.com/DeveloperLaunchpad/) I'm going to be doing the one from January.

```
FirstNumber=0
SecondNumber=0
MathOP=" "
answer=0
#I know caluater spelled incorrectly its I will get to that later 
print("python caluater")
FirstNumber=input("enter your first number")
MathOP=input(" + , - , * or / ")
SecondNumber=input("enter your second number")

if MathOP=="+":
    answer==FirstNumber+SecondNumber
    print(str(FirstNumber) + "+" + str(SecondNumber) + "=" +str(answer))
elif MathOP=="-":
    answer=FirstNumber-SecondNumber
    print(str(FirstNumber) + "-" +str(SecondNumber) + "=" + str(answer))
elif MathOP=="*":
      answer=FirstNumber*SecondNumber
      print(str(FirstNumber)+ "*" + str(SecondNumber + "=" +str(answer))
elif MathOP=="/":
      answer=FirstNumber/SecondNumber
      print(str(FirstNumber )+ "/" + str(SecondNumber) + "=" +str(answer))

else:
    print("congrats you broke me")
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to what the error is. I should downvote this, but I don't want to waste what little rep I have lol.

Comment: @JoeD downvoting questions costs you no reputation

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip! Only applies to downvoting answers then? @Ifma

Comment: @JoeD Yes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis inside the line above it.

Change

```
print(str(FirstNumber)+ "*" + str(SecondNumber + "=" +str(answer))
```

to

```
print(str(FirstNumber)+ "*" + str(SecondNumber) + "=" +str(answer))
```

and you should be good to go.